# Nginx duplicate log_format name timed_combined error

Tags: web-services, nginx, server

I am getting this error:

```
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] duplicate "log_format" name "timed_combined" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:8
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

whenever I am tring to start or restart my nginx server. This does not happen before. Here's the first few lines of code in my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

```
# You may add here your
# server {
#       ...
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts
log_format timed_combined '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  '
        '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $request_time';
```

Answer (score 9):

The "timed_combined" log_format is predefined in sources; you need to use your name, something like:

`log_format my_log '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  '
        '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $request_time';`

After that you need to re-define access_log:

`access_log /path/to/access.log my_log`